# Removing glitches from edges of a polygon

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, geometry

Code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12gi6TDNLaYkz3qNkATryW_d-8QysH60L#scrollTo=xvNP-erJHlcP

[image]

As you can see, there are glitches at each corner. And I would like to remove those glitches to make the corners sharp. My approach would be get the nearest points based on some distance threshold for each exterior coordinates, and then calculate the smallest rectangular polygon with those points. and finally union() the polygon and those calculated rectangular polygons to close the gaps. What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While a link to complex code is acceptable, the Question is still expected to contain a minimal subset of code which reflects your issue. Try to avoid "What do you think" as the question, since *opinion-based* questions are closed here.

Comment: Have you just tried to simplify the geometry?

Comment: Unfortunately was not so good idea. I tested it, and even simplifying with a tolerance of 1 unit does remove extra vertices from the corners it is also changing the geometry so that it is not especially rectangular any more. Maybe you could create a grid of suitable cell size, select the cells that intersect, and then union.